# Verify a statement on a random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given a random variable $x$ with finite expected value $E(x)$, i need to verify whether the following holds:

if $E(x) < 0$ and $\theta \neq 0$, such that $E(e^{\theta x}) = 1$, then $\theta > 0$

I proceeded by noting that

$$E(e^{\theta x}) > E(x) \implies e^{\theta x} > x $$

Then taking logs on both sides and solving for $\theta$ i get

$$\theta > \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$

Which however seems a really strange result to me given the nature of x. Any ideas of what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Jensen's inequality,

$$ E\left[\exp\left\{\theta X\right\}\right] > \exp\left\{\theta E[X]\right\}$$

for any $\theta \neq 0$. Moreover, as $E[X] < 0$,

$$ \exp\left\{\theta E[X]\right\} \begin{cases}
> 1 & \text{if } \theta < 0 \\
< 1 & \text{if } \theta > 0
\end{cases} $$

So when $\theta < 0$, we have

$$ E\left[\exp\left\{\theta X\right\}\right] > \exp\left\{\theta E[X]\right\} > 1$$

which contradict to $E\left[\exp\left\{\theta X\right\}\right] = 1$

Therefore, when $E\left[\exp\left\{\theta X\right\}\right] = 1$, we have $\theta > 0$

Comment: Given that $e^{\theta x}$ is a convex function, now i see it.. would you mind highlighting the mistake in my approach?

Comment: Actually I do not quite follow your first statement already. $X > Y$ almost surely implies $E[X] > E[Y]$, but the converse does not hold in general.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!